# Access button reference from other class

Tags: android, button

I have somthing like that:

```
public class A()
{
    private Button myButton;

    public void setMyButton(Button myButton)
    {
        this.myButton = myButton;
    }

    public Button getMyButton()
    {
        return myButton;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        setMyButton(button);
    }


public class B()
{
    public void exampleMethod()
    {
        A aObject = new A();

        Button button = aObject.getMyButton();
    }
}
```

Button in class B is always null. I tryied that:

In class A

```
public Button myButton;
```

In class B

```
A aObject = new A();
Button button = aObject.myButton;
```

but it is not working too.
I am sure that first is button initiate, then geting button reference. I checked that using logs.
I don't know what is going on, becasue "getMyButton" in class A work fine. How can I get reference of button from class A in class B?
What is the best way to do that?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to do?

if these classes are `activities` then whatever you are doing, you are doing it very wrong.

Comment: Class A is a MainActivity class. In this class I have a few buttons. After click one of thoes Dialog with edittext shows up. To prepare and create Dialog I have other class named DialogBuilder. After close Dialog I want to set button title as text typed in edittext. Dialog has positive and negative buttons.

Comment: Ok, I'll post the answer

Comment: could you post your code of what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are creating new java object of your activity on your own. Please try to get existing object of an created activity; so that you will get activity context and activity properties as well.

Answer (score 0):

The button is always null because its set in onCreate, which is not automatically called.  Let me guess, A is supposed to be an Activity subclass, based on the signature, right?  In that case you're doing things really wrong.

*You cannot create an Activity via new, it won't be properly initialized.

*Accessing views of an Activity like that is really weird.  It makes more sense to pass the view into B, as B is likely owned by A.   If the Activity A doesn't own B, you're probably doing something really wrong.  Pretty much if you need to do this you've probably misarchitected something.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are doing will only works in JAVA and not in ANDROID.

Its because of ACTIVITY class. Activity class reference will be created only when its life cycle is created and you cannot pass the UI elements of one activity to Another.

As the button is associated with the `'A'` Class in your case and if you want this in Class `'B'` you have to start Activity and its life cycle and also `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Other way is get the data that you want from any class and publish the value in 'A' class itself. this can be done by `startActivityForResult();`

Comment: Ok I understand so to do that I need to start new Activity but set layout as activity_main and then I can pass UI elements as well, right?

Comment: Please follow this:http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html